# Dropbox Sync API startLink() method not working

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I'm developing an Android app that uses the Dropbox Sync API to upload files. I have already created the app on Dropbox, gotten the APP_KEY and the APP_SECRET. I have included all the necessary libraries, set the proper keys in my activity code and the Manifest. My app is similar to the HelloDropbox sample provided in the documentation, but when I click on the "Link to Dropbox" button which is supposed to display a place to enter my dropbox credentials, nothing happens. Here's the source code:

```
package com.diamondtrust66.helix.player;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager;
import com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFile;
import com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFileInfo;
import com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFileSystem;
import com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxPath;

public class HelixPlayer extends Activity {

private static final String appKey = "1234-my-key";
private static final String appSecret = "1234-my-secret";

private static final int REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX = 0;

private TextView mTestOutput;
private Button mLinkButton;
private DbxAccountManager mDbxAcctMgr;
private DropboxAPI<?> mDBApi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_helix_player);
    mTestOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_output);
    mLinkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.link_button);
    mLinkButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickLinkToDropbox();
        }
    });

    mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), appKey, appSecret);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mDbxAcctMgr.hasLinkedAccount()) {
        showLinkedView();
        doDropboxTest();
    } else {
        showUnlinkedView();
    }
}

private void showLinkedView() {
    mLinkButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mTestOutput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void showUnlinkedView() {
    mLinkButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mTestOutput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void onClickLinkToDropbox() {
    mDbxAcctMgr.startLink((Activity)this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            doDropboxTest();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FAILURE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mTestOutput.setText("Link to Dropbox failed or was cancelled.");
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private void doDropboxTest() {
    try {
        final String TEST_DATA = "Hello Dropbox";
        final String TEST_FILE_NAME = "be like that.mp3";
        DbxPath testPath = new DbxPath(DbxPath.ROOT, TEST_FILE_NAME);

        // Create DbxFileSystem for synchronized file access.
        DbxFileSystem dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());





        // Print the contents of the root folder.  This will block until we can
        // sync metadata the first time.
        List<DbxFileInfo> infos = dbxFs.listFolder(DbxPath.ROOT);
        mTestOutput.setText("\nContents of app folder:\n");
        for (DbxFileInfo info : infos) {
            mTestOutput.append("    " + info.path + ", " + info.modifiedTime + '\n');
        }

        // Create a test file only if it doesn't already exist.
        if (!dbxFs.exists(testPath)) {
            DbxFile testFile = dbxFs.create(testPath);
            try {

                File myFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/alarms/be like that.mp3");
                //testFile.writeString(TEST_DATA);
                testFile.writeFromExistingFile(myFile, false);
            } finally {
                testFile.close();
            }
            mTestOutput.append("\nCreated new file '" + testPath + "'.\n");
        }

        // Read and print the contents of test file.  Since we're not making
        // any attempt to wait for the latest version, this may print an
        // older cached version.  Use getSyncStatus() and/or a listener to
        // check for a new version.
        /*if (dbxFs.isFile(testPath)) {
            String resultData;
            DbxFile testFile = dbxFs.open(testPath);
            try {
                resultData = testFile.readString();
            } finally {
                testFile.close();
            }
            mTestOutput.append("\nRead file '" + testPath + "' and got data:\n    " + resultData);
        } else if (dbxFs.isFolder(testPath)) {
            mTestOutput.append("'" + testPath.toString() + "' is a folder.\n");
        }*/
    } catch (IOException e) {
        mTestOutput.setText("Dropbox test failed: " + e);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run the unmodified Hello Dropbox example on the same emulator/device where you're experiencing this problem?  You can try replacing the app key/secret in the sample with your own as well.  If those also fail, it may be there's something wrong with the configuration of your device which is keeping the API from launching a browser to complete authentication.  If the example works, but your app doesn't, then I'd suspect something misconfigured there.  Can you check with a log statement whether your call to startLink() is actually happening?  Do you see anything appear in LogCat after that point?

The best way to debug this further might be to open a suppot ticket.  Use the API Support link here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Comment: I found that when I uninstall the Hello Dropbox example, my app works. I'm using ICS 4.0.4, and I can't figure out why the two apps would not work on the same phone.

Comment: If you're seeing the two apps conflict with each other, I'd suspect that you might not have the correct app key in your AndroidManifest.xml.  Your app needs to register for URLs with a custom schema containing your app key.  If two apps register for the same schema, then authentication will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, the startLink() was doing nothing when I tried to use the same dropbox app credentials I was using with another android app my device had installed (although not running), but it didn't work. So you have two options: Uninstall any other android app using the same credentials OR create another dropbox app and renew the set of app/pass keys. Only then the Dropbox Login Dialog appears.